# Ruby on rails DRY strip whitespace from selective input forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, whitespace, dry, strip

I'm fairly new to rails so bear with me.

I want to strip whitespace from a selective group of input forms.

But I would like a DRY solution.

So I was thinking there might be a solution such as a helper method, or a custom callback. Or a combination such as `before_validation strip_whitespace(:attribute, :attribute2, etc)`

Any help is awesome! Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have this in my model file ...

```
  include ApplicationHelper

  strip_whitespace_from_attributes :employer_name
```

... and I have this in my ApplicationHelper ...

```
  def strip_whitespace_from_attributes(*args)
    args.each do |attribute|
      attribute.gsub('\s*', '')
    end
  end
```

but now I'm getting the error message:

```
undefined method `strip_whitespace_from_attributes' for "the test":String
```

**EDIT II -- SUCCESS**

I added this StripWhitespace module file to the lib directory

```
module StripWhitespace

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def strip_whitespace_from_attributes(*args)
      args.each do |attribute|
        define_method "#{attribute}=" do |value|
            #debugger
            value = value.gsub(/\s*/, "")
            #debugger
            super(value)
          end
      end
    end
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, StripWhitespace)
```

and then added this to any model class this wants to strip whitespace ...

```
  include StripWhitespace
  strip_whitespace_from_attributes #add any attributes that need whitespace stripped
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with sth like this (not tested):

```
module Stripper # yeah!
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def strip_attributes(*args)
      mod = Module.new
        args.each do |attribute|
          define_method "#{attribute}=" do |value|
            value = value.strip if value.respond_to? :strip
            super(value)
          end
        end
      end
      include mod
    end
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Stripper
  strip_attributes :foo, :bar
end

m = MyModel.new
m.foo = '   stripped    '
m.foo #=> 'stripped'
```

Comment: @KendallWeihe - I am not sure when including ApplicationHelper within model got so popular, either why. Helpers are module which are to be associated with views and hence including them in the model breaks the MVC pattern. Apart of that, method you are trying to call in class context is defined as instance method hence it is not available.

Comment: @BroiSatse what about adding that method to a controller? does that break the MVC pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your attributes in to a single array (perhaps there's a `[:params]` key you can use instead), you can do the following:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_create strip_whitespace(params)



  private

  def strip_whitespace(*params)
    params.map{ |attr| attr.strip }
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think there is `before_validation` method defined on the controller.