# How do I pass arguments into a module in a before_save hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# will strip whitespace of certain attributes
module StripWhitespace
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :strip_whitespace
  end

  # Strips white space from these user attributes
  def strip_whitespace(attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      self[attr] = send(attr)&.strip
    end
  end
end
```

and I'm currently including that in the a model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

include StripWhitespace

end
```

However, I want to be able to pass an argument into a `before_save` hook. Something like this:

```rb
# user.rb

COLS_TO_STRIP = %i[first_name last_name location phone city]

before_save strip_whitespace(COLS_TO_STRIP)
```

This doesn't work either way. Being new to ruby, I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Should I be doing this in the model? Or the module? Is my module set up correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby on rails DRY strip whitespace from selective input forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295576/ruby-on-rails-dry-strip-whitespace-from-selective-input-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be passed through callback hooks like below -

```
before_save -> { strip_whitespace(COLS_TO_STRIP) }
```